# Oracle VM VirtualBox cannot create new Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, runtime

I am trying to use the Oracle VM VirtualBox. However, when I try to create a new machine (I don't have any yet), I get the following error:

> #### VirtualBox Manager has stopped working
>
> A problem caused the program to stop working incorrectly...

The step I use to create a new machine are either of the following:

1. **New Button** in Main Tool Bar
2. Machine → New
3. <kbd>Ctrl + N</kbd>

I am using **VirtualBox 5.2**. How can I stop this from occurring?

My Hardware and Software Specs:

1. Computer Model - **Dell Vostro 1500**
2. Operating System - **Windows 7 Ultimate x86**
3. Processor - **Intel Core 2 Duo T5270 @1.40GHz**
4. RAM - **2 GB**

Comment: Are you attempting to create a virtual machine to run a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system? Edit your question.  Have you tried to remove and then reinstall the current version of VirtualBox?  What version of VirtualBox are you attempting to use currently? Edit your question

Comment: @Ramhound I am using version 5.2 And, I am yet to create a VM

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?